# Invalid default value for 'account_id'

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have tried to create a table in a MySQL database with **phpmyadmin**.

The problem occurred when I try to execute this following query:

```sql
CREATE TABLE users(
    account_id INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT '100001',
    PASSWORD INT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    NAME VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    account_type VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    balance DOUBLE(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    created_at DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY(account_id)
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

The error says:

```
MySQL Error: #1067 - Invalid default value for 'account_id'
```

Please help to fix this thing! I have tried many solutions but none of them seem to work

Comment: Your password...is an `INT`? Remember, when you have problems, please **include the exact error text** and don't just come in screaming "I have a problem" with no further details.

Comment: Tip: Do not use floating point numbers for monetary work. Always, always use fixed-place representations like `DECIMAL(12,2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your definition is really confused.  For instance:

- Default values should match the type of the column.
- A default value is not appropriate for an auto-increment column.
- A length parameter is inappropriate for `double`.  And probably for integers as well.
- `0` is not an appropriate default value for a date.

So, you seem to want something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    account_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PASSWORD INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    NAME VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    account_type VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    balance DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    created_at DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (account_id)
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Comment: thank you, it worked when i tried your query, i was trying to create a table from the browse menu without any sql command and thats what caused the issue, now its working fine. thanks! Good day sir

Answer (score 0):

Remove default from account id.
Use below.

```
CREATE TABLE users(
account_id INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PASSWORD INT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  NAME VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 account_type VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 balance DOUBLE(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
```

created_at DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY(account_id)
) ENGINE = INNODB;

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna `AUTO_INCREMENT` then you cant set the default value

```
account_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

Or if you need a default value then you have to remove `AUTO_INCREMENT`

```
account_id INT(20) NOT NULL  DEFAULT '100001',
```